# How to generate random time delay in VHDL

Tags: random, vhdl

I want to implement a PUF using ring oscilator in VHDL, I want to generate 32 Ring Oscilator with different gate delays. How can I do that?
My code is as follows:

```
generate_ros:
for i in 0 to 31 generate
ro_1: ring_oscilator 
    generic map (delay => 200 ps , chain_len => 15) -- 200ps shall be random
    port map (
      rst_i => s_rst,
      clk_o => s_inp(i)
    );
 end generate;
```

Comment: What exactly is a PUF? Is this for simulation or synthesis?

Comment: Physical Unclonable Function - [PUF](http://rijndael.ece.vt.edu/puf/background.html).  How to synthesis a definable delay is an exercise left to the discretion of the reader. It's the very manufacturing process mismatch PUFs 'quantize' that makes it hard to specify.  From the link you can see a ring oscillator is recommended for a device ID. The idea is to prevent someone (else) in the manufacturing chain from counterfeiting silicon products. Also see [Improved Ring Oscillator PUF: An FPGA-friendly Secure Primitive](http://rijndael.ece.vt.edu/puf/paper/jofc2010.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for links and explanation. I want to simulate it first and then synthesize it. For simulation of different ring oscilator on FPGA I need different delay time for each ring oscilator. If I choose same delay for all of them it will produce a constant PUF :) which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Improved Ring Oscillator PUF: An FPGA-friendly Secure Primitive](http://rijndael.ece.vt.edu/puf/paper/jofc2010.pdf) all ROs should be identical and have the same delay (most [ring oscillators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_oscillator) works that way).

The delay in a ring oscillator loop is caused by random process variation and systematic variation and not by nominal delay (as explained in 3.1.1). That's why when you create `n` ROs, you'll get (with high probability) `n/2` 0's and `n/2` 1's at each positive edge of your clock. You do not need to define delay at HDL level.

Comment: I need this 200ps delay just for simulation, not for synthese. This is a part of ring_oscilator design:        `gen_chain:
  for i in 1 to chain_len-1 generate
    chain(i) <= not chain(i-1) after delay;
  end generate;
  chain(0) <= not chain(chain_len-1) or rst_i after delay;

 ro_o <= chain(chain_len-1);` As you know "after" statement is ignored by synthesizer, it is only for simulation.

Comment: @MübinIcyer: RO design requires only an odd number of NOT gates connected to each other.

Answer (score 0):

To realize the PUF on FPGA, you should use Hard Macro for single RO FPGA design. As the PUF depends upon static delay variation ( Process dependent variation ), Hard Macro will fix the design parameter(LUT, slice) on FPGA. Once you got one, you can replicate as many as you want, in your case 31.